# function with array variable

Tags: php, function, arrays

How do I pass an array through a function, for example:

```
$data = array(
    'color'  => 'red',
    'height' => 'tall'
);

something($data);

function something($data) {
    if ($data['color'] == 'red') {
        // do something
    }
}
```

how can I get the function to recognize `$data[color]` and `$data[height]`?

Comment: Do you mean you need the function to be able to modify the array?

Comment: I need the function to understand that $data[color] equals red. So that I can use: if ($data[color] == 'red') { do something } inside the function

Comment: you have your function already. what's the problem with it?

Comment: I edited the post so that it hopefully makes a bit more sense. Does what I have look correct?

Comment: Quotes are missing around color in the if. Could be your problem.

Comment: Nope, i just typed it wrong here. Im working on a wordpress plugin thats driving me nuts. I guess my problem is elsewhere. Thanks for all the help yall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the easiest answer is the right one:

```
$data = array(
    'color'  => 'red',
    'height' => 'tall'
);


function something($data) {
    if ($data['color'] == 'red') {
        // do something
    }
} 

something($data);
```

Arrays don't need a special handling in this case, you can pass any type you want into a function.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$data = array('color'  => 'red', 'height' => 'tall');

function something($data) {
    if ($data['color'] == 'red') {
        // do something
    }
}

something($data);
```

As remark, you need to quote your strings: `$data['color']`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to make some validations to the parameter to make the function more reliable.

```
function something($data)
{
    if(is_array(data) and isset($data['color']))
    {
         if($data['color'] == 'red')
         {
            //do your thing
         }
    }
    else
    {
         //throw some exception
    }
}
```